# Annotate mocked objects in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I need to mock object using Mockito with annotation and then utilize that annotation. Is there a way to add annotation to a mocked object?

Comment: Where are you getting that `@Order` annotation from?

Comment: You are right :) . Yikes! So my question need to be re-written. How do I mock a class with @Order?

Comment: Add annotation to type you mocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do so:

```
public class YourTest {
  @Order public static class YourAnnotatedClass extends YourClass {}

  @Mock YourAnnotatedClass yourAnnotatedClass;

  // ...
}
```

This will ensure that your type has the annotation you want in its hierarchy. Mockito's overrides are based on Proxy/CGLIB/ByteBuddy and not exactly on any proper class to be annotated or used in reflection.

In fact, there may be a few reasons to build out the subclass as a fake or manual mock without using Mockito at all, such as:

- if the annotation needs to be on the lowest (most-specific) subclass in the hierarchy
- if you don't need any other Mockito functionality
- if the class that needs to be annotated/subclassed is the class under test, because you should be testing the class as it is meant to be used (a subclass) rather than Mockito's mocks/stubs